# master-detail relationship: showing detail as null until drilled

Tags: obiee, oracle-bi

I have 2 graphs with master-detail relationship about company hierarchy. First graph groups number avarages by departments, second one groups by the divisions of the selected department in the first graph. Question: is there any possible way to not show any results in the second graph until master event clicked on the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, since master-detail is one single analysis which also means one data stream.